# Load balance nodejs app for zero downtime deploy with nginx serving different static assets

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have 2 directories www-1 and www-2 and both have the the same nodejs app. which has some jade views, some endpoints, etc.

Also have 2 upstart scripts that run:

```
PORT=5000 node www-1/app.js

PORT=5001 node www-2/app.js
```

Now, i have the following nginx configuration to load balance incoming traffic to one or the other.

```
upstream backend {
   server 127.0.0.1:5000 fail_timeout=0;
   server 127.0.0.1:5001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript image/x-icon image/jpeg;
    gzip_vary on;
    charset UTF-8;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name myserver.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        proxy_connect_timeout 2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$ {
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        root /home/user/myserver.com/www-1/public;
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/dciccale/2331d2e0a1a6e76e05bd

This works, however as you can see in [line 34](https://gist.github.com/dciccale/2331d2e0a1a6e76e05bd#file-my-nginx-conf-L34) i am also serving all statics from nginx, however i want some way to specify the root to be www-1 or www-2 depending on which server is up.

Let me explain why:

In the server i have a git repo which normally I would `git pull` whenever i make a change. then i would build the new code `gulp dist` which generates a `dist` directory and then `rm -rf www-1 && cp -r dist www-1` so while that last command executes, there may be some downtime in www-1 (app running in 5000) for serving for example jade files giving a 500 for not finding the view or whatever, so nginx will balance to port 5001. that works, but also nginx would fail serving static files from www-1 if those static assets are being replaced. After this also i would restart the first upstart script to re-run the new deployed app. After this i would do the same process for www-2.

so that is my question, how to make that `root` for static assets dynamic. or if there is a better way of handling this i would appreciate some help.

**EDIT:** A second configuration

I setted up another configuration which works however for some seconds a user could see the updated content while another one could see the old content, the best i could get.

By creating 2 new server blocks that listen to port 3000 and 3001 which do a proxy_pass to 5000 and 5001 respectively and each of this server blocks has a route for static assets, one pointing to www-1 and the other to www-2.

Also needed to add `http_502` and `http_404` to the `proxy_next_upstream` directive to make sure that all failing requests should be load balanced (like a 404 in an image that is being replaced)

https://gist.github.com/dciccale/2331d2e0a1a6e76e05bd#file-my-nginx-2-conf

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting a version id in the URL for static content and simply leave the previous version alive as long as you're refreshing your back ends.